# Mysqli query with bind params using fetch_array

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I know how to use `fetch_array` instead of `printf()` function when expressing rows from database using mysqli bind function.

How can I use `$row->mysqli_fetch_array` and then use `$row[0],$row[1]` instead of using the `printf()` function every time I want to print something from database?

Comment: Sorry, none of that makes sense. Can you try and rephrase the question?

Comment: It could be tricky. Refer to my article for the possible solution: [Usability problems of mysqli compared to PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison#compatibility)

Comment: also, please post a code sample of what you were doing and part where you've stuck.

Comment: @MrJustin. Updated the answer bro :) with the corrections.

Comment: Could you please check and let me know if you face any hindrance in development . Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning an associative array from a prepared statement you can follow up the procedure like this as follows.

```
<?php
$category = $_POST['category'];
$sql = "select id, name from items where category = ?";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $category);
if($stmt->execute())
{
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$a  = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); // this does work :)
}
else
{
    error_log ("Didn't work");
}
?>
```

You can use while loop for printing up the value over from the associative array.

```
while($a = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo 'Id: '. $a['id'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Name: '.$a['name'];
}
```

**Output:**

```
Id: 1

Name: Example
```

Comment: thanks, i want to ask what parameter in your example is $query? $sql? Should it be $result = $sql->get_result(); ?

Comment: @MrJustin. I have rectified my output and now it is fine. Share thoughts. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to help you. You can accept the answer if is resolves your problem. Since if you accept it the other developers will be feeling useful so that they can rectify the errors in a shorter period of time. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly you can try:

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
foreach($row as $cell) {
  echo "$cell";
}
```

Comment: He is asking how to get it from a *prepared* query